# Ruby - How to do IO.popen with spaces in path

Tags: ruby, windows

I am trying to run the following code on Windows:

```
require 'rbconfig'
is_windows = (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)
OUT_FILE = "test/simulation/out.txt"
File.delete OUT_FILE if File.exists? OUT_FILE 

if is_windows
    var = IO.popen("C:\\Program Files\\Microchip\\MPLABX\\v5.45/mplab_platform/bin>mdb.bat ./test/simulation/sim_instructions.txt > " + OUT_FILE)
else
    var = IO.popen("#{ENV['MPLABX_ROOT']}/mplab_ide/bin/mdb.sh ./test/simulation/sim_instructions.txt > " + OUT_FILE)
end
sleep 1
if File.exists? OUT_FILE 
    file_contents = File.read OUT_FILE
    file_contents.gsub!("/n", "")
    print file_contents
end
```

I keep getting the error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I am not very familiar with Ruby, so can someone assist how I use IO.popen when I have a space in the file path. Or a different function that something similar to IO.popen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following solution of just surrounding the path with quotations. So now here is the line that I changed with the correct output:

```
var = IO.popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Microchip\\MPLABX\\v5.45/mplab_platform/bin/mdb.bat" ./test/simulation/sim_instructions.txt > ' + OUT_FILE)
```